# What is "unable to create a constant value of type ''. only primitive types or enumeration types are supported in this context."

Tags: c#, entity-framework

WaiverID is an int so I am not sure what the non primitive type in question is.

```
 var originalWaivers = _context.SurchargeWaivers
.Where(x => updatedWaivers.Select(waiver => waiver.WaiverID).Contains(x.WaiverID));
```

I am trying to query the db for the original entities so that I can update them.

**UPDATE:**
More specifically, why is this a problem. Why is it that a list will work but an IEnumerable is a problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems `updatedWaivers` is the problem. Instead of performing an inner query for each item, just store the ids into a `List` and use it:

```
var idList = updatedWaivers.Select(waiver => waiver.WaiverID).ToList();
var originalWaivers = _context.SurchargeWaivers
                              .Where(x => idList.Contains(x.WaiverID));
```

Comment: Thanks, buy why is this an issue?

Comment: Because LINQ to Entities is trying to convert `updatedWaivers.Select(waiver => waiver.WaiverID)` into an actual SQL statement, and since `updatedWaivers` is actually in memory, and not in the database, it fails to do so.